# Push array into array on ruby by just one level

Tags: arrays, ruby, immutability

Given:

```
a = [[1,"a"],[2,"b"]]
b = [[3,"c"],[4,"d"]]
```

I want to turn `a` into `[[1,"a"],[2,"b"][3,"c"],[4,"d"]]`. How can do this without `+`? It creates a new array, which I want to avoid.

```
(a << b).flatten(1)
# => [1, "a", 2, "b", [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
```

Comment: Note that your expected `a` is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.concat(b)
```

...............................

Comment: but it creates a new array which i want to avoid.

Comment: `a.concat(b)` does not create a new array?

Comment: I thought concat also creates a new array like +=, doesn't it?

Comment: `a.concat(b)` will modify the contents of `a`, so no new array is created.

Comment: Easy to be sure: `a = [1]; old_id = a.object_id; a.concat([2]); old_id == a.object_id` should convince you no new objects are being created by `concat`.

Answer (score 2):

```
> b.inject(a, :<<)
#=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,"a"],[2,"b"]]
b = [[3,"c"],[4,"d"]]
a[a.length, 0] = b
a
# > [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
```

Comment: Learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

`concat` is the answer, but you could do this:

```
a.object_id    #=> 70223889895340
a.replace(a+b) #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
a              #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
a.object_id    #=> 70223889895340
```

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
a.push(b.shift) while b.any?
```

Comment: `a.push(*b)` is much less worse than yours.

Comment: @sawa, hah. Didn't know about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
a + b 
=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
```

Comment: `a+b` creates a new oject, something the OP wanted to avoid (i.e., `(a+b).object_I'd != a.object_id`).