# Operator Array#<< failed in shorthand form of reduce

Tags: arrays, ruby, reduce

There is well-known shorthand form to pass block to any method, based on [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) implementation.

Instead of:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(0) { |memo, e| memo + e }
# or
[1,2,3].reduce { |memo, e| memo.+(e) }
```

one might write:

```
[1,2,3].reduce &:+
```

The above is an exact “synonym” of the latter “standard notation.”

---

Let us now have two arrays:

```
a = [[1,"a"],[2,"b"]]
b = [[3,"c"],[4,"d"]]
```

While both

```
b.reduce(a) { |memo, e| memo << e }
# and
b.reduce(a) { |memo, e| memo.<<(e) }
```

will correctly update `a` array inplace, exactly as `a.concat(b)` would do:

```
#⇒ [[1,"a"], [2,"b"], [3,"c"], [4,"d"]]
```

the short notation all if a sudden raises an exception:

```
b.reduce(a) &:<<
#⇒ TypeError: [[1, "a"], [2, "b"]] is not a symbol
```

What am I missing? Ruby 2.1.

---

*P.S.* Casted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240574/push-array-into-array-on-ruby-by-just-one-level).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
b.reduce(a) &:<<
```

won't work because it's not valid method calling. Instead, pass the symbol as the last argument:

```
b.reduce(a, &:<<)
# => [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
```

---

When you call:

```
[1,2,3].reduce &:+
```

`&:+` is an argument to the method. It's actually equivalent to:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(&:+)
```

If the last argument to a method is preceded by `&`, it is a considered a `Proc`
object (the `Symbol` to `Proc` trick). Then it's removed from the parameter list, and is converted into a block , the method then associate the block.

Comment: I will drop here an addendum for future visitors: `TypeError ... is not a symbol` is thrown because [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), being called without a block, still accepts _the latter `Symbol` argument_, that is converted to proc and used as block. That said, the ampersand above is superfluous: `b.reduce a, :<<` will do the trick.